# Logged in cognito users don't show up in identity pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

A user signs up, and verifies their account. Then the user logs in:

```
// in real life, these fields are replaced with my values
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            console.log('You are now logged in.');

            // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR_IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
                Logins: {
                    'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html

And so, the logged in user is thus authenticated and allowed to use the various pages within the web application.

Still, during this time, zero users show up in the identity pool
[image]

should these registered / logged in users be showing up here? or, am I misunderstanding the point of an identity pool?

Comment: where did you extract the identity pool snapshot above from? I am trying to find where the logged in user count is in the AWS Cognito console, but I can't find it. thanks

Comment: login to aws console > cognito > manage federated identities > your dashboard will have a graph for each existing identity pool. if you dont have any, create one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, I just think the call to your identity pool isn't being made. My guess is you're creating those credentials, but not actually populating them. Can you try calling get or refresh on that object, then check again?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js 
I had followed "use case 4" for the authentication process. At what point in that would the get / refresh happen? then to get the information of that user as they go from page to page, I used "use case 16".

Comment: Try immediately after initializing it. I might be wrong, this would confirm one way or another. If I'm not, I'll have the docs updated to make that clear.

Comment: That worked. FYI the integration between the two services happens in section 17, but it isn't obvious why they're separate or necessary. Maybe they could explain that :)

Comment: I fail to understand the difference between use case 4 and 17. Once a user gets the tokens isn't he logged in? Use case 4's title is : Authenticating a user and [[establishing a user session]] with the Amazon Cognito Identity service.

Comment: Why again do I need to call refresh() on the credentials? To me this looks just like a configuration object I hand to the AWS service (e.g. S3). But the service always failed until I did your recommended refresh() before initializing S3. I'm confused and don't get it.